# Vector bundle, nonexistence of Euclidean metric

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Milnor-Stasheff "Characteristic classes" problem 2-C says:

> Any vector bundle over a paracompact base space can be given a Euclidean metric

in other words, if $\pi : E \rightarrow B$ is a vector bundle and $B$ is paracompact, there is a continuous function $\mu : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that on every fiber $\pi^{-1}(x)$, $\mu$ is a positive-definite quadratic form.

Is there a nonexample when $B$ is not paracompact? I don't have any strategy to prove that no such $\mu$ can exist.

Comment: Problem 2-D suggests the long line $L$. I think the idea is that in this case, the function $\mu$ lets you pick a continuous nonvanishing section of the tangent bundle given by $\mu^{-1}(\{1\})$, and this lets you "integrate" to define an increasing function from $L$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I'm not entirely sure, so I'd love to see another answer.